# Is modeprobe automatically creates a sysfile interface - /sys/module/?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, lttng

My embedded box doesn't support modeprobe because of security issue. I am trying to do an insmod of the kernel modules. The code I am using lttng. I see that lttng does the kernel object insertion using modeprobe. For my case, I have disabled those modeprobe and I am doing an insmod for it. I am suspecting that because I am doing insmod the sys interface is not created. On the other hand, the modeprobe part I am assuming that it is creating a sys interface. Is it true that modeprobe creates a sysfile interface? If it is true, then what can I do here as I am using insmod.

Comment: Disabling `modprobe` but leaving `insmod` available does exactly zero good for increasing security... It merely provides a slight inconvenience to anyone who wants to inject a kernel module...

Answer (score 0):

Actually modprobe is just like 'insmod' except that modprobe resolves module dependencies and finally invokes init_module system call to insert the module. So, in both the cases (modprobe and insmode) init_module() system call is invoked which actually creates sysfs entry for the module.

In lttng case I think there are a lot of modules that needs to be loaded, and there may be dependencies among them, inserting modules one by one using insmod will be very difficult task, first of all you need to find which module depends on what and you have to insert the modules accordingly.

So better thing is use the modprobe or just use the lttng on another machine where you have the modprobe and note the order of the modules and write a script to insert them all.